# How to put crosshairs (vertical line) in line graph using achartengine in android

Tags: android, achartengine, linegraph

I am using achartengine graph library for line chart in android. Can some one advice me on putting crosshairs (A vertical line which moves on all data points when user touches on the graph)  My requirements match to a implementation like this  http://www.jqchart.com/samples/ChartFeatures/Crosshairs or there is another library available that can be implemented easily in android for vertical line cross hair.

Answer (score 1):

you will able to accomplish the task by adding an onClickListener on the chart and when a valid point is detected you add another drawable on top of the chart. Keep the chart in a frameLayout and add that drawable in the form of imageView and show/hide the imageView on certain events as per your requirement.
edit:also in your case you will need to modify the height of the drawable everytime